# How to loop case of statement?

Tags: java, case

I'm writing a very very simple database program in JAVA and i want to loop case statement to work as a menu if you know what i mean. I know it's simple but how it should be done ?:)     THX !

```
while(s!="q"){
    switch (s) {
    case "1": 

        System.out.println("Podaj imie :") ;
        String imie = sc.next();    
        System.out.println("Podaj nazwisko :") ;
        String nazwisko = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Podaj email :") ;
        String email = sc.next();
        Kontakt wpis = new Kontakt(imie,nazwisko,email);
        bazaDanych.baza.add(kontakt);
             break;
    case "2":  
        System.out.println("Podaj nazwisko osoby ktora chcesz usunac z bazy :");
        String nameToDelete = sc.next();
        kontakt.usunOsobe(nameToDelete, bazaDanych);
             break;
    case "3":  
        kontakt.wypiszBaze(bazaDanych);
             break;
    case "4":  
        System.out.println("Podaj nazwisko osoby ktorej szukasz :");
        String nameToSearch = sc.next();
        kontakt.pokazOsobe(nameToSearch, bazaDanych);
             break;
            //        case "q":  System.exit(0);
    //                 break;

    default: System.out.println("Nieobslugiwany klawisz");
             break;
    }

}
```

Comment: is `s` a String.  If so, you have to use `s.equals("q")`

Comment: Add `s = ...` at the end of each `case`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating the value of `s` presently so it will execute only once. You need to update the value of `s` to get it executed in a loop